# What would be DTM direct call rule in GTM

Tags: google-tag-manager, adobe-analytics

I am new to Google Tag Manager.

Currently Adobe dynamic tag manager gets tracking data from my site using Direct Call Rule. I am trying to understand what is direct call rule in Google Tag Manager (GTM)?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In GTM there is dataLayer object.
In implementation you can use something similar to

```
dataLayer.push({
    'event':'YourAction', 
    'eventCategory':'xxxx', 
    'eventAction': action, 
    'eventLabel': 'xxxx', 
    'eventValue': 'xxxx', 
    'eventNonInteraction': true
});
```

Above is similar to `_satellite.track('YourAction');`

then you need to create a rule with custom event where you need to provide YourAction as name.

In your Tag where you wish to use this direct call rule, as running rule you should use created rule.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I always use

```
dataLayer.push({'event': 'DirectCallRuleName'});
```

In GTM do the following

1. **Triggers** → **NEW**

   - *Trigger Type*: Custom Event
   - *Event Name*: DirectCallRuleName (or any other name you have chosen)
   - *This trigger fires on*: All custom events
2. **Tags** → **NEW**

   - *Track Type*: Event
   - *Category, Action, Label* as you wish
   - *Triggering*: Trigger you have created in 1.